# Removing Objects From ArrayList Sometimes Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

So, I am making a game where a tank has to shoot down planes with bullets. I have an ArrayList of planes and all their properties, and I also have an ArrayList of all the bullets, their angles, and coordinates.

I made a `for` loop of all the planes where I displayed them on the screen and changed their coordinates. Inside of that `for` loop, I made another `for` loop that looped through all the bullets. This is where I displayed the bullets and changed their y and x coordinates.

For each plane in the ArrayList, there was a variable that calculated its distance from all the bullets on the screen. I made it so that when the bullets made contact with the plane, both the bullets and the planes were `remove` from their ArrayLists. However, about 10-20% of the time, a bullet that hit 1 plane removed all the rest of the planes and the next wave of planes came in.

Does anyone have an idea what my problem could be?

Here is some of my code:

```
if(thisArrayList.size() > 0){

        for(int x = 0; x < thisArrayList.size(); x ++){

            if(thisArrayList.get(x)[4] == 1.0 && thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= -50){

                g2d.drawImage(plane10, (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[0] - 50), (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[3] - 50), null);

            }else if(thisArrayList.get(x)[4] == 2.0 && thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= -50){

                g2d.drawImage(plane20, (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[0] - 50), (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[3] - 50), null);

            }else if(thisArrayList.get(x)[4] == 3.0 && thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= -50){

                g2d.drawImage(plane30, (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[0] - 50), (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[3] - 50), null);

            }

            thisArrayList.get(x)[0] += thisArrayList.get(x)[2];

            g2d.setFont(new Font("Source Sans Pro Black", 15, 15));

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            g2d.drawString(((thisArrayList.get(x)[1])).toString(), (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[0] - 10), (int) (thisArrayList.get(x)[3] + 7));

            if(thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= Main.widthOfScreen + 50 && thisArrayList.get(x)[3] == 100){

                thisArrayList.get(x)[3] = 205.0;

                thisArrayList.get(x)[0] = -60.0;

            }else if(thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= Main.widthOfScreen + 50 && thisArrayList.get(x)[3] != 100){

                if(thisArrayList.size() == 1){

                    isDone = "yes";

                    Panel.waveNum ++;

                    isVisible = false;

                    thisArrayList = new ArrayList<Double[]>();

                }else{

                    thisArrayList.remove(x);

                }

            }

            try{

                for(int i = 0; i < BulletTracker.bullets.size(); i ++){

                        //double dist = 100;

                        if(BulletTracker.bullets.size() > 0 && thisArrayList.size() > 0){

                            if(BulletTracker.bullets.size() > 0 && thisArrayList.size() > 0 && thisArrayList.get(x)[0] >= -50){

                                try{

                                    thisArrayList.get(x)[5] = Math.sqrt(((BulletTracker.bullets.get(i)[1] - thisArrayList.get(x)[0]) * (BulletTracker.bullets.get(i)[1] - thisArrayList.get(x)[0]))  
                                    + ((BulletTracker.bullets.get(i)[2] - thisArrayList.get(x)[3]) * (BulletTracker.bullets.get(i)[2] - thisArrayList.get(x)[3])));

                                }catch(Exception e){

                                    thisArrayList.get(x)[5] = 50.0;

                                }

                            }else{

                                thisArrayList.get(x)[5] = 100.0;

                            }

                            if(thisArrayList.get(x)[5] <= 50){

                                thisArrayList.get(x)[1] -= 10;

                                if(thisArrayList.get(x)[1] <= 0){

                                    if(thisArrayList.size() != 1){

                                        thisArrayList.remove(x);

                                    }else{

                                        isDone = "yes";

                                        Panel.waveNum ++;

                                        isVisible = false;

                                        thisArrayList = new ArrayList<Double[]>();

                                    }

                                }

                                BulletTracker.bullets.remove(i);

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    }catch(Exception e){

                        System.out.println("Sorry. There was an error.");

                        isDone = "yes";

                        Panel.waveNum ++;

                        isVisible = false;

                        thisArrayList = new ArrayList<Double[]>();

                    }
```

By the way, `thisArrayList` is the ArrayList of planes and `thisArrayList.get(x)[5]` is the distance of each planes from all the bullets. There are a lot of unneeded try and catch statements and unneeded code that I never deleted.

Comment: can you format the code so its legible??

Comment: There you go. I fixed it. It just didn't work when I pasted it.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a threading issue. Are there multiple threads accessing the ArrayList? If so, or you don't know, try synchronized block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but it looks like you have `thisArrayList.remove` inside loop that loops through the `thisArrayList`.

Look at the following example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < thisArrayList.size(); x++) {
    final int element = thisArrayList.get(x);
    if(condition) {
        thisArrayList.remove(x);
    }
}
```

If the condition is met then element is removed, but since you are still in a for loop then you do the following:

Let's suppose we have `thisArrayList = { 1, 2, 3 }`

- Suppose condition is true for **x=1** so remove element at position x=1
- You continue executing the code outside the if
- No code left so for loop increments **x** and proceeds
- Now we've got **x=2**
- But since the element at **x=1** was removed then the list looks like this: `{ 1, 3 }`
- Then since **x=2** it's outside list and condition of for loop: `x < thisArrayList.size()` is false

You see where it's going...

The problem is that you should try to avoid removing and iterating the lists at the same time because it leads to skipping the elements.

The correct solution is to mark the elements for removal.
It can be done via external list e.g. `List<int> toBeRemoved` with indexes to be removed.

- If you want to remove item you add it to `toBeRemoved`
- Then after the entire for loop, you loop through `toBeRemoved` and carefully remove the items

Or you can just do:

```
if(condition) {
     thisArrayList.remove(x);
     --x;
     continue;
}
```

It will ensure that you do not skip any element.

Anyway, better solution to iteration and removal at the same time is to use iterators:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = thisArrayList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   int s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
   // Do something
   i.remove();
}
```

By using iterators you ensure that you iterate every element and nothing bad happens.

**Using the iterators is a good practice** (not every time, but in such scenarios!)